# Where to ask questions related to the junction between programming and mathematics?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am asking very basic but deep questions related to programming, mathematics etc...

Unfortunately I am losing my reputation. Suggest for me the best site in the Stack Exchange network to ask questions like these:

> Is a program written in any programming language ultimately a function/relation in math or not?

Comment: Can you give a link to a question?

Comment: What kind of questions are you asking and on what sites? I can see you have accounts on both the Methematics site and Stack Overflow, so the question here lacks context.

Comment: My question is generally of (briefly) like this ....

1) Is program written in any programming language is ultimately a function/relation in math or not ?

Comment: I think its a very basic , but i have argument with colleagues and which cant be found by net surfing  i want to ask here . But i think its a little bit high level elite site . That's why i wanna know which site is best for such questions .

Comment: This feels like a question in which answers would be very much based on opinion would be extremely subjective.  I don't think there is a site where such a question would be acceptable.

Comment: I would try to define a lot more what you mean by "function/relation". Also; which site did you post this on? Stack overflow will certainly find it too conceptual

Comment: I think that people may thinks it as a silly question that's why they are voting down my question , but it is really important for me and my colleagues...

Comment: @hanu so this is a question you have asked already?

Comment: I deleted my question 5 minutes back due to loss of 4 reputations .. I clearly explained all terms in precise ....

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yeah i asked halfen hour back and deleted ..

Comment: @hanu if this is/was a real question you asked, then rather than paraphrasing, you should quote the entire question so we can evaluate the actual question.  With the little you have given, I don't think this would be a good question anywhere, but perhaps the full question might be more acceptable

Comment: I'm still wondering on which site you posted that question.

Comment: In fact i briefly asked here , In my original question that i asked on Stackoverflow , I elaborately asked .. Is this too much under-valued question to ask on any site on Stackoverflow network ? I thought stackoverflow scale varies from beginner to elite . As a beginner one thinks philosophically from basics relating to his background . As a mathematical student i wanna map my course contents to it .

Comment: Link to question (+10k + OP): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23032402/mathematical-functions-vs-programs

Comment: @Oded Yeah its my question .

Comment: @hanu SO is beginner to expert in **practical problems**. Not conceptual ones. Asked properly this could be one for Computer Science, as suggested by gene

Comment: And please check http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask so you improve your chances of not being downvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a basic question that the sub-discipline of computer science called "denotational semantics" tries to answer.  Therefore the [computer science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) ought to be a good place for this and similar ones.

FWIW, denotational semantics generally does succeed in modeling any sequential program running on a formalized computer (with storage, address space, variables, pointers/arrays, and I/O channels). Handling parallelism is harder, but possible in somewhat limited ways.